# yii2 urlManager 'urlFormat'=>'path', error

Tags: php, yii2

```
Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Setting unknown property: yii\web\UrlManager::urlFormat
1. in /server/www/xmgstudent/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php at line 197
```

Comment: 欢迎。 你的问题什么？Welcome. What exactly is your question?

Comment: l want  http://*****/teacher-time/index?a=1    http://***/teacher-time/index/a/1

Comment: can you post your urlManager config code?

Comment: 'urlManager' => [
'urlFormat'=>'path',            
'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'showScriptName' => false,

            'rules' => [
                 ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['avatar']],
            ],
        ],

Answer (score 1):

In Yii2, `UrlManager` class does not have `urlFormat` property. Instead, you can use [`enablePrettyUrl`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$enablePrettyUrl-detail) and set it to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I copied same **urlManager** you are using and I also got the same error.

**Solution**

Remove `'urlFormat' => 'path'` from urlManager config.

```
'urlManager' => [  
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true, 
    'enableStrictParsing' => false, 
    'showScriptName' => false, 
    'rules' => [ 
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => ['avatar'],
            'teacher-time/index/<id:\d+>'=>'teacher-time/index',
        ], 
    ], 
],
```

And it works !

Answer (score -2):

it's your nginx or apache rewrite mistake.
apache:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerName test-yii2.com
DocumentRoot F:/wamp64/www/yii2/frontend/web
<Directory  "F:/wamp64/www/yii2/frontend/web">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
</Directory>
```

Comment: It does not seems to be related to question.